# Should I add a key to the items of my REST API response?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have an REST API endpoint which the JSON response looks like:

```
{
    "products": [
        {"id": 1040, "price": 2.95, ...}
        {"id": 4545, "price": 3.95, ...}
    ]
}
```

One of my colleagues suggested that I should add a key for each item in the list. He said it would make easier to browse the browse the API. The example above would become:

```
{
    "products": {
        "1040": {"id": 1040, "price": 2.95, ...}
        "4545": {"id": 4545, "price": 3.95, ...}
    }
}
```

Making it will not be harmful for my API's performance and I can understand how it should improve the browsability. Should I do that? Is there any example of public API that does something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Is the response an answer to a query that's more like `GetListOfProducts()` or `GetProductIndex()`? Is the result intended to be iterated over or used as a single-product lookup by `id`? Is the sort-order significant?

If it's more like `GetListOfProducts()` with sort-order implications and/or the intention of iteration, like displaying the records in a table, stick with what you have. It's probably trivial for your API consumers to search or index the items.

If it's more like `GetProductIndex()` and is intended to be *used like an index*, and if sort order doesn't matter, consider sending it in the 2nd form. But even in this case, remember that it's probably trivial to index (or `search()` or `filter()`) the array client-side. So, I'd be a little hesitant: Consider whether it's more difficult for the client/consumer to index and search a list or for the server to inject a sort order (and the client to respect that order) if needed on a property set that has no inherent ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think about the sort order issues. In my case the order doesn't matters, but there should be other places where it does. My API could become inconsistent if I return a map in some endpoints and a list elsewhere.